# Drupal Site is very Slow after migrating

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, server

I migrate a Drupal website from live server to my staging server. 

 **Ist** 
I export full database and import in local and delete all cache tables data. 

 **2nd** 
I download zip file of code and upload in staging server and change database username , pass in setting.php file

Now My web site at staging is very very slow it takes upto 5 minutes to load any page

can any one let me know where I make mistake in migration and now how I can make fast my site at staging. I think it is not reason of staging server because same site at my own machine is also slow when I setup it on my local machine. same site is very fast at production server.I am new to drupal please anyone point my mistake where I make mistake so site is slow

Comment: Dear brother please read question carefully it is self explanatory. If you have no answer then please do not underrate anyone questions
Let me know if you want more description
Thanks Brother

Comment: it'll load slow at first while it rebuilds the cache. other than logs as suggested by Graham below, check the resources of your staging (and/or local) vs live server (memory, php.ini settings, storage, processing)

Answer (score 0):

Check error logs (Drupal's "Recent log messages" under the "Reports" menu, as well as PHP error logs and Apache logs on your server). Use Firebug in Firefox, or dev tools in other browsers to see if some assets (images, CSS files, JS files) are missing.